# Dynamic togglable Bootstrap's radio button group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-group

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.x and I want to have an toggleable *Status* radio button group which change its radio label's colors based on active item selected.

I have two radio buttons: *Published* and *Draft*.

I need to swap `.btn-success` class when *Published* is selected and `.btn-default` when it isn't.

I also need to swap `.btn-danger` class when *Draft* is selected and `.btn-default` when it isn't.

**Markup** (defaults to *draft* state):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" data-toggle-default-class="btn-default">
 <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle-class="btn-success">
  <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" id="status-published" />
  Published
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-xs btn-danger active" data-toggle-class="btn-danger">
  <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" id="status-draft" checked />
  Draft
 </label>
</div>
```

I'm using `data-toggle-default-class` attribute on `.btn-group` to tell default button class color. Moreover, I'm using `data-toggle-class` attribute on labels to tell which button class color it should use when selected.

**JavaScript**:

```
$('.btn-group[data-toggle=buttons]').each(function (i, e) {
    var default_class = $(e).data('toggle-default-class') || 'btn-default';

    $(e).find('label')
        .click(function () {
            $(e).find('label')
                .each(function (i, e) {
                    if ($(e).hasClass('active')) {
                        $(e).removeClass($(e).data('toggle-class'))
                            .addClass(default_class);
                        $(e).find('input')
                            .removeAttr('checked');
                    } else {
                        $(e).removeClass(default_class)
                            .addClass($(e).data('toggle-class'));
                        $(e).find('input')
                            .attr('checked', 1);
                    }
                });
        });
});
```

It works, but only when you swap choices. If you click twice on one choice, it'll completely misbehave.

Here's the fiddle to see the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Hq78X/1/

I'm looking for a fix to this and I'm also open to suggestions on an unobtrusive way to achieve that. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hope it helps someone, I got it working changing JS a bit:

```
$('.btn-group[data-toggle=buttons]').each(function (i, e) {
    var default_class = $(e).data('toggle-default-class') || 'btn-default';

    $(e).find('label')
        .click(function (event) {
            $(e).find('label')
                .each(function (i, e) {
                    if (!(e == event.target)) {
                        $(e).removeClass($(e).data('toggle-class'))
                            .addClass(default_class);
                        $(e).find('input')
                            .removeAttr('checked');
                    } else {
                        $(e).removeClass(default_class)
                            .addClass($(e).data('toggle-class'));
                        $(e).find('input')
                            .attr('checked', 1);
                    }
                });
        });
});
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Hq78X/2/

Thank y'all anyway. :)